# How could I prove that $B$ reduces to $A$ in polynomial time in this case?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, decision-problem, polynomial-time

Let $A$ be a decision problem with at least one yes instance and at least one no instance. Also let $B \in \textbf{P}$. How could I prove that B reduces to A in polynomial time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just decide B within the reduction and output a word in A / not in A accordingly

Comment: @dave Make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a\in A$ and  $b \notin A$.

the reduction defined as follows:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
a & x\in B\\
b & x\notin B
\end{cases}$$

It is easy to see that $f \in \text{POLY}$ since $B\in\text{P}$, and the correctness is trivial.